# Best practices for learning Blender

Tags: workflow

When I get an idea for something I'd like to make in Blender, I hit up Google for specifics, then blender SE when I get stuck.

I'm very overwhelmed by the immensity of Blender and I'm a little afraid that this self-directed approach is going to lead me to develop bad habits. Is there a "best practice" way of learning to use Blender?

Comment: Open ended questions are generally a bad fit for Stack Exchange. It would be better if your question could have one, definitive answer, rather than any number of possibly correct, but highly variably, answers.

Comment: This type of question is considered off topic. However, there are links to a bunch of tutorial sites in the beginners reference on Blender.SE meta: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40/beginners-reference

Comment: Your question is valuable, but in my opinion goes more into the direction of project management and project organization within Blender. Maybe ask it at blenderartists.org

Answer (score 3):

You may wish to check out the [Blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Main_Page). For instance, it has a series of articles on [starting to use Blender](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface) for the first time, and it has many articles for specific topics.

Some tutorial websites you may find useful include:

- [BlenderCookie](http://cgcookie.com/blender/) and their [Blender Basics](http://cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-courses/blender-basics-introduction-for-beginners/) tutorial series
- [BlenderGuru](http://www.blenderguru.com/), offering a tutorials of varying difficulty for specific tasks with general lessons
- [BlenderDiplom](http://blenderdiplom.com/en/), another similar website

You can also ask for critiques on the [BlenderArtists](http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/) forum.

I would recommend checking the regular contests on websites like BlenderGuru and BlenderCookie. Even if you don't feel qualified to enter, give it your best shot – you may learn something along the way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes blender is a large topic to learn.

I wouldn't be concerned with learning bad habits. Find a way to do what you need to do.

Over time you will come across different ways to do the same thing, some of them may be from new features added to blender, some will just be short cuts that you haven't found yet. You just need to stay open to the thought of always learning and be willing to try different ways of doing tasks.

Even the best of us do things differently today than we did 5 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Blender is immense and does have a lot of features/functions, so you will find people have many different methods and workflows. 
The best practice would really be learning how to use the necessary Hotkeys that you'll be using the most. If your goal is to create a decent model in the most efficient and time-conserving way possible, memorizing Hotkeys is important.

You can also check out http://darkscarab.com. Fairly small community for people who aren't comfortable with tons of people. The members are also quite knowledgeable and helpful.