# Beginner Guide for Efficient Modeling

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm fairly new to Blender and 3-D modeling in general.  I created my first model and was pretty proud of it.  However, when I finally thought about it and noticed it, I decided 400,000 faces may have been a few too many.  So to my question:

Does anyone have a basic set of rules and/or a guide they follow as they model that will help lead to proper technique and efficiently rendered models? Triangles vs Quads, when to (and not to) subdivide/subsurf, is there anything wrong with making a high-res version and decimating/shrinkwrapping after it's done?

Like I said, I'm a beginner so I want to make sure I'm doing things *correctly* and won't be forming a bunch of bad habits I will have to correct later.  So a step by step workflow, or tips on things to avoid, etc.  I've been doing a lot of research, but haven't found this type of information broken down well.  I don't necessarily need a large amount of detail - just a basic list to act as a guide of more things to research as I model.

(It is worth mentioning that most of my models will be used in a realtime application, so I am aware I have to get my polycount WAY down)

Comment: Hi. I think this question is probably more suited to [blenderartists](http://blenderartists.org/) as it is quite broad and will be primarily opinion based. This site is suited to more specific questions with definite answers.

Comment: Quick search for keywords *topology* and *high poly* here could lead to some helpful posts.

Comment: This is a pretty broad subject, and one bound to be very opinion based. As mentioned above check blender artists forum and get back if you have any specific doubts or difficulties. [These tutorials](https://www.google.pt/search?q=blender+game+assets&tbm=vid) may also help

Comment: Cgcookie has a few good courses (not free), I liked this a lot: https://cgcookie.com/course/creature-modeling-for-production/

Comment: Thank you everyone, "topology" was the keyword I was looking for.  I'm not quite used to all the lingo yet.  Searching topology has given me plenty of great material and I've already reduced my poly count on a plane model from about 20k down to 7.4k.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a duplicate of:

[Best practices for learning Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2355/best-practices-for-learning-blender)

You might also check:

1. https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=blender+best+practices&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8
2. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Avoiding_Headaches_Early_On:_Good_3D_Modeling_Practices